# Workaround for using Session State in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, architecture

I am working on ASP.NET MVC 4 project. I have the following scenario to implement:

```
Page A | <-> Page B | <-> Page C
                    | <-> Page D
```

- Page A calls Page B
- Page B calls Page C, once Page C finishes it's work, it returns to Page B
- Page B might also call Page D, once Page D finishes it's work, it returns to Page B
- Once Page B finishes it's task, the control returns to Page A.

These pages are typically "Create" pages in MVC creating a new model and saving it to database. Once saved the default action to return is the list view for that models. But I am hijacking the flow and calling the "create" page from a different page and using `session` to store the `UrlReferrer` and redirecting it back to the original page that made the request instead of falling back to the default list view page for that model.

Even though I am not using the session variable of one page in the other and I am disposing the session variable once the flow completes, I am still making the MVC pages `stateful` by temporarily storing the `redirection` details.

Is there a workaround to achieve this behavior without using session state?

**EDIT: Code**

```
   //Get
   Function Create() As ActionResult
        If Session("RequestedUrl") Is Nothing Then
            Session("RequestedUrl") = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath
        End If
        Return View()
    End Function


    <HttpPost()>
    Function Create(saveModel As SomeModel) As ActionResult
        If (ModelState.IsValid) Then
            //Save Model

            If Session("RequestedUrl") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Session("RequestedUrl").ToString()) Then
                Dim path = Session("RequestedUrl").ToString()
                Session("RequestedUrl") = Nothing
                //Go to the initial page that made the request
                Return Redirect(path) 
            End If
            //Go to default List view
            Return RedirectToAction("Index") 
        End If
        Return View("Create")
    End Function
```

Comment: Can you add some code to show how you are `session`

Comment: Why not just use a querystring parameter, like returnUrl, when you call a child view to tell it to go to that page after it does what it's supposed to do instead of the default flow?

Comment: @rikitikitik Ussing Querystring works for single level redirection. But if you see from the scenario, I cannot return to Page A from B once Page B goes to Page C or D as new Page B called from C or D has no clue who called it initially.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temp database table and use that but you would still need some id from the session back to the table. Unique key. You could store it in a cookie on the users local pc and then pass it in and read it in mvc?

Answer (score 0):

You could just put RequestedUrl hidden in the form so that the client sends it to you when he submits instead of maintaining it on the server. Or even better, instead of keeping the whole URL, several hidden parameters from which you can reconstruct the URL after the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
That still works for single redirection. 
But if you see from the scenario, I cannot return to Page A from B once Page B goes to Page C or D as new Page B called from C or D has no clue who called it initially.

Comment: You could keep passing the value but that would be cumbersome. Keep it in a cookie as @user3759531 suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Session seems rather heavy-handed here, particularly because the client never sees anything change from their point of view. They are just loading page A, even though behind the scenes you are calling B, C and D to reuse code. Since all of this is happening within one http request, you should consider using `Context.Items` instead:

http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/courseware/cse2030/2004/state.html

Also, default ASP.NET session state will block on each session ID. When you hit two pages simultaneously, with the same session ID, one will run to completion before the other even starts. Avoiding it altogether will allow your CRUD operations to happen in parallel, which is either a good or a bad thing depending on how well the rest of your backend code handles simultaneous CRUD operations.